# Extracting Excel Charts as PNG Files. Getting some corrupted photos as a result

Tags: python, excel, charts, png

I am trying to save some Excel charts as PNG files on my documents folder, so I can later automatically send outlook emails with the corresponding charts images on the email body.

However, some png files are being extracted as corrupted  unable to open.

Below is the code I am currently using and, in theory, is working fine. Any ideas to do to stop this corrupted png files?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
def chart2():

app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook_file_name = r"S:\File\US.xlsm"
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename=workbook_file_name)


app.DisplayAlerts = False

i=1
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
    for chartObject in sheet.ChartObjects():
        print(sheet.Name + ":" + chartObject.Name)
        chartObject.Chart.Export(r"S:\File\chart" + sheet.Name + "-" + chartObject.Name + ".png")
        i += 1
        
chart2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue of Zoom in / Zoom out on the Excel Worksheet. I had big zoom on some sheets and the graphs that were not currently "showing" on the screen were not loading the information.

As a result, this was generating an PNG corrupted file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).